# How to use GNU Privacy Guard to verify authenticity of MediaWiki download

Tags: gnupg

I just downloaded the latest version of MediaWiki and want to check it's authenticity. They provide a signature file on their download page http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Download. How would one use this with the gpg command on Linux?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The process I have used on Ubuntu 12.04 is as follows

(1) Download the mediawiki code

`wget http://download.wikimedia.org/mediawiki/1.20/mediawiki-1.20.2.tar.gz`

(2) Download the signature file

`wget http://download.wikimedia.org/mediawiki/1.20/mediawiki-1.20.2.tar.gz.sig`

(3) Get the public keys of mediawiki signers

Click on the GPG keys link and then click "Get keys as a text bundle", or just go straight to: https://www.mediawiki.org/keys/keys.txt.

Save the file as `keys.txt`

(4) Import the public keys

`gpg --import keys.txt`

(5) Verify the file

`gpg --verify mediawiki-1.20.2.tar.gz.sig`

This is successful but I do receive the following warning however:

```
gpg: WARNING: This key is not certified with a trusted signature!<br />
gpg:          There is no indication that the signature belongs to the owner.
```

Since I downloaded the keys from what I believe to be a trusted source I am not worried about this. There must be a way to mark keys as trusted.

Comment: +1; FYI, to eliminate that error message, type `gpg --edit-key <key-id>` (where <key-id> is the key you imported), then type `trust` and set the trust value you want.  Or, if you don't plan to receive files from this source and you are not afraid of meddling, you can just ignore the message.  It's just a warning after all.